# BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82: Method [all] does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Model code is below listed

```
?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class monthlyActivity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'monthly_activities';
}
```

and controller is 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class monthlyActivity extends Controller
{
    //

    public function show()
    {
        $monthly = monthlyActivity::all();
        return view('show',['monthly' => $monthly]);
    }
}
```

show.blade file is below

```
<tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($monthly as $mon)
                {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <?php echo $mon->year ?>
                            </td><td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td><td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td><td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td><td>
                            <?php echo $mon->id ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php

                }
                ?>
```

in route file below is the mention route for this particular page

> Route::get('show', 'monthlyActivity@show');

and am getting the error in **all** which is declare in controller, i don't know how can i solve this error

Comment: It can't differentiate between your controller and model as they have the same name. Either use the model fully namespaced, change its name, or add a use statement for the model at the top of the controller giving the model an alias

Answer (score 1):

You are using same name for controller as well as model. So the error is here:

```
$monthly = monthlyActivity::all();
```

line line trying to find `all()` function inside your `controller` class because of name conflict. So change the name of model or use full name-space with model to differentiate it.

Comment: i have change the name of controller then its error occur FatalErrorException in monthlyActivityController.php line 13:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\monthlyActivity' not found

Comment: Check the error: **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\monthlyActivity'** it is self explanatory

Comment: can you please tell me how can i define the model name so that it cannot be conflict with controller need your help

Comment: could not understand how can use namespace i have check sample code as well they can also use like mine but they didnot get any bad error

Answer (score 1):

Model names are in camelCase in Laravel with the exception of first alphabet capital so your model name should be: MonthlyActivity so in you model change line:

```
class monthlyActivity extends Model
```

to

```
class MonthlyActivity extends Model
```

Then also change your file name of model to `MonthlyActivity.php`

Now about controllers , its not a tight rule but suggested that you add a Controller suffix in name. It helps you to avoid these name conflicts and their name is also preferrably should start from uppercase letter so I suggest you change your controller name to:

```
class MonthlyActivityController extends Controller
```

Change controller file name as well to: `MonthlyActivityController.php`

In your controller now you will use:

```
$monthly = MonthlyActivity::all();
```

Make sure that on top of controller you have included the model with:

```
use App\MonthlyActivity;
```

Change your route to: `Route::get('show', 'MonthlyActivityController@show');`

Then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now try your your program, it should work as expected.